# Question on Cardinality

Tags: functions, cardinals

[image: This is the question]
[image: This is the model answer given]

I understand how to prove on whether the function is a 1-to-1 or a onto function but i just can't figure out how did they get the equation in the beginning as the equation wasn't given in the question. Thank You!

Comment: They constructed a function that when given the domain $[2,5]$, the range would be $[-2,3]$.

Comment: *Technically codomain, since with the bijection you're proving it's the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a restriction of a line which goes from through points $(x_1,y_1) = (2,-2)$ and $(x_2,y_2) = (5,3)$. Using the formula for the equation of a line through two points $$y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)$$ we obtain:

$$f(x) - (-2) = \frac{3 - (-2)}{5 - 2}(x - 2) \implies f(x) = \frac{5x-16}3$$

Comment: What if it is not a straight line graph? May i know how do you know that this is a straight-line graph

Comment: @JaySun There are other bijections, of course. The straight line is a standard technique so I tried it first.

Comment: Do you mind to guide me on what other technique can be done to determine an equation in this case? Thank you

Comment: @JaySun I meant that the linear function is a standard technique to show that two segments have the same cardinality. You can also try finding an equation of a parabola segment $ax^2 + bx + c$ through the two points. But  your problem requires you just to provide one bijection, memorizing the standard example is enough.

Comment: alright, thank you very much for your explanation. Appreciate